# Can a cubic polynomial in two real variables have two monkey saddles?

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, roots, maxima-minima

> Can a cubic polynomial $f(x,y)$ have two [monkey saddles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_saddle)?

A cubic polynomial can have at most 4 critical points and from the inequaility (3.1) in  [Counting Critical Points of Real Polynomials in Two Variables by Alan Durfee, Nathan Kronefeld, Heidi Munson, Jeff Roy, Ina Westby](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324459?seq=7) it follows that at most three of them can be saddles. That this upper bound is attained is shown in [Can a cubic polynomial in two real variables have three saddle points?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446848/497175) How about monkey saddles, can a cubic polynomial have more than one?

Comment: well, if we insist that one occurs at the origin at height zero, then the function is homogeneous cubic; after which

Comment: " In contrast, the monkey saddle has a stationary point of inflection in every direction. "